# Why grpreg library and gglasso library in R are giving different results for group LASSO?

Tags: r, feature-selection, unsupervised-learning, lasso-regression

I have been trying to do unsupervised feature selection using LASSO (by removing class column). The dataset includes categorical (factor) and continuous (numeric) variables. [Here is the link](https://github.com/myildir3/Datasets/blob/master/hepatitis.data.xlsx). I built a design matrix using `model.matrix()` which creates dummy variables for each level of the categorical variables.

```
dataset <- read.xlsx("./hepatitis.data.xlsx", sheet = "hepatitis", na.strings = "")
names_df <- names(dataset)
formula_LASSO <- as.formula(paste("~ 0 +", paste(names_df, collapse = " + ")))
LASSO_df <- model.matrix(object = formula_LASSO, data = dataset, contrasts.arg = lapply(dataset[ ,sapply(dataset, is.factor)], contrasts, contrasts = FALSE ))

### Group LASSO using gglasso package
gglasso_group <- c(1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 10, 10, 11, 11, 12, 12, 13, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 17)
fit <- gglasso(x = LASSO_df, y = y_k, group = gglasso_group, loss = "ls", intercept = FALSE, nlambda = 100)
# Cross validation
fit.cv <- cv.gglasso(x = LASSO_df, y = y_k, group = gglasso_group, nfolds = 10)
# Best lambda
best_lambda_fit.cv <- fit.cv$lambda.1se
# Final coefficients of variables
coefs = coef.gglasso(object = fit, s = best_lambda_fit.cv)

### Group LASSO with grpreg package
group_lasso <- grpreg(X = LASSO_df, y = y_k, group = gglasso_group, penalty = "grLasso")
plot(group_lasso)
cv_group_lasso <- cv.grpreg(X = LASSO_df, y = y_k, group = gglasso_group, penalty = "grLasso", se = "quick")
# Best lambda
best_lambda_group_lasso <- cv_group_lasso$lambda.min
coef_mat_group_lasso <- as.matrix(coef(cv_group_lasso))
```

If you check `coefs` and `coef_mat_group_lasso`, you will realize that they are not the same. Also, the best lambda values are not the same. I am not sure which one to choose for feature selection.

Any idea of how to remove intercept in `grpreg()` function? `intercept = FALSE` is not working.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Please refer to the [gglasso paper](http://users.stat.umn.edu/%7Ezouxx019/Papers/gglasso-paper.pdf) and the [grpreg paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs11222-013-9424-2).

**Different objective functions**. On page 175 of [grpreg paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs11222-013-9424-2), the author performs a step called group standardization, which normalizes the feature matrix within each group by right-multiplying an orthonormal matrix and a non-negative diagonal matrix. After the group lasso step with group standardization, the estimated coefficients are left-multiplied by the same matrices such that we obtain the coefficients of the original linear model. In such a way, however, the group lasso penalty is not equivalent to that without group standardization. For the detailed discussion, please also find it on page 175.

**Different algorithms**. The `grpreg` uses block coordinate descent, while `gglasso` uses an algorithm called groupwise-majorization-descent. It is natural to see small numerical differences when the algorithms are not the same.